# Applaying SVG css filter on element causes its unvisibility

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg-filters

I am trying to use css blur effect. I want to make it cross browser (Chrome & Firefox).
On chrome, I can simply use `-webkit-filter: blur(4px);` but on firefox, I've to use SVG effects.
So, in my CSS I've added:

```
.blurred {
    filter: url(#blur);
}
```

My HTML markup (HTML5):

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="blurred">Lorem ipsum</div>
<svg height="0">
<filter id="blur">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
</filter>
</svg>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, applying .blurred class on any element, make it blank (or white, because I can still click links etc). 
Any solution?

Edit:
I've checked, and problems appears only when style are loaded from stylesheet file. When its in style tag in html file - blur works properly :(

Comment: I've found it somewhere as a fix.

Comment: This works [perfectly fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lm6zvn4/), I'm unable to reproduce the error

Comment: @ZachSaucier please see my edit - I've checked again, and it works for me too, when styles and markup and in the same file. When css code is loaded from external file, it doesn't work

Comment: That's impossible for us to debug with this information.

Comment: Just create index.html file, place html code and SVG there. Link to external style.css file - put `filter: url(#blur);` there.

Comment: I've done the process before and it's worked for me, there's no reason to assume it won't now. Why not recreate the situation using jsfiddle or some other similar website?

Comment: You didn't put styles in external file. JSfiddle puts css in same document (using style tag).

Comment: Here is example of the issue: CSS loaded from external file:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzxlC

Answer (score 1):

url(#xxx) is shorthand for url(#the file I'm in#xxx) so when you put it in your .css file it becomes url(file.css#xxx) and there is no xxx in the css file, it's in the html file.

The answer is to prepend the html file name. i.e.

```
.blurred {
    filter: url(file.html#blur);
}
```